# NativeScript RadListView component template

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, ios11.4

I am trying to use an Angular component as the template for `RadListView`.

```
<StackLayout>
  <RadListView [items]="stories"
               marginRight="-2"
               separatorColor="transparent"
               height="100%">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate
                 let-story="item">
      <NewsItem [story]="story"></NewsItem>
    </ng-template>
  </RadListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I get the following error.

> file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js:57:124: JS ERROR Error: onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension() ProxyViewContainer(435)

Comment: Perhaps your `NewsItem` hasn't extended `CustomLayoutView`. The easiest answer is to just put a `<StackLayout></StackLayout>` around your content.

Comment: hmm I have a `StackLayout` around the content inside of `NewsItem`

Comment: That's not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The template itself must have a container.

```
<StackLayout>
  <RadListView [items]="stories"
               marginRight="-2"
               separatorColor="transparent"
               height="100%">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate
                 let-story="item">
      <StackLayout>
        <NewsItem [story]="story"></NewsItem>
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </RadListView>
</StackLayout>
```